# onPageLoad and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I use Keyframes and the Jquery plugin Smoothstate to make smooth and animated transitions between my pages with this method :

https://css-tricks.com/add-page-transitions-css-smoothstate-js/

The problem was that my jQuery plugins will not work, I needed to refresh the page in order for it to work again.

So I used this method : [smoothState.js conflicting with other plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822384/smoothstate-js-conflicting-with-other-plugins)

It works on my page **main.js** which contains all my jquery plugins.

**Exemple of my main.js :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    (function($) {
      $.fn.onPageLoad = function() {

        // HERE THERE ARE ALL THE PLUGINS.

      };
    }(jQuery));

    ('body').onPageLoad();

});
```

The problem is that I have other jquery plugin in my **index.php** (I can't move it because the jquery contains php).
If the plugins in my **main.js** run well, the plugin in my **index.php** doesn't run.

If think they are a conflict ?

**Exemple of my index.php :**

```
<body>

    <!-- HERE THERE ARE ALL THE HTML. -->

    <!-- HERE THERE ARE ALL THE PHP. -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            (function($) {
            $.fn.onPageLoad = function() {

                // HERE THERE ARE ALL THE PLUGINS.

            $('body').onPageLoad();

        });

    </script>

</body>
```